# Inner queries are returning more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 
    FORM_OF_PAYMENT_CD paymentMethod,   
    DECODE (CC_TYPE_CD, 'V', 'VS', 'M', 'MC', 'A', 'AM', 'D', 'DC', NULL) paymentSubMethod,
    PAYMENT_AMOUNT amount,
    LPAD(SUBSTR(trim(PCI_PKG.D_CC(op.CC_NUMBER, 654916320742196284)),
    LENGTH(trim(PCI_PKG.D_CC(op.CC_NUMBER, 654916320742196284)))-3),
    LENGTH(trim(PCI_PKG.D_CC(op.CC_NUMBER, 654916320742196284))) , '*') ccNumber,
    CC_EXP_DATE ccExpirationDate,
    IAI.ADDRESS addressLine1,
    IAI.ZIP zipCode,
    IAI.ZIP_EXTENSION zip4Code,
    DECODE(ORM.EPP_CHANNEL_ID, NULL, NULL, (ORM.EPP_CHANNEL_ID ||'^'   || ORM.EPP_ACTOR_ID   ||'^'   || OP.EPP_TOKEN_ID   ||'^'   || OP.EPP_TOKEN_TYPE   ||'^'   ||       (
        SELECT DISTINCT AUTH.EPP_PAYMENT_ID
        FROM OEMADM.AUTHORIZATION_INFO AUTH
        WHERE AUTH.ORDER_KEY= OP.ORDER_KEY   )) ) eppPaymentInfo,
    (SELECT AI.AUTH_CODE
     FROM AUTHORIZATION_INFO AI
     WHERE AI.PAYMENT_TYPE_CD = op.PAYMENT_TYPE_CD
       AND AI.ORDER_KEY = op.ORDER_KEY
       AND AI.AUTH_TYPE_CD = 'PRE' ) AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
    (SELECT AI.AUTH_STATUS_DESC
     FROM AUTHORIZATION_INFO AI
     WHERE AI.PAYMENT_TYPE_CD = op.PAYMENT_TYPE_CD  
       AND AI.ORDER_KEY = op.ORDER_KEY
       AND AI.AUTH_TYPE_CD = 'PRE' ) PRE_AUTHORIZATION_MSG,
    (SELECT UPDATED_DT   
     FROM SETTLEMENT_REFUND_RESP   
     WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE_CODE = 'SET'   
       AND PAYMENT_TYPE_CD ='DQP'   
       AND ORDER_KEY = OP.ORDER_KEY   ) REQUEST_DATE ,
    OP.PAYMENT_TYPE_CD paymentTypeCode 
FROM 
    OEMADM.ORDER_PAYMENTS OP,   
    OEMADM.IDENT_ADDRESS_INFO IAI,   
    OEMADM.ORDER_MASTER ORM 
WHERE 
    OP.ORDER_KEY           = 'ow-srso-229451126' 
AND ORM.ORDER_KEY          = OP.ORDER_KEY 
AND IAI.IDENT_ADDR_INFO_ID = OP.PAYER_ADDR_INFO_ID
```

Above query is not executing because

> inner queries are returning more than one row.

Comment: Ok,good to know.Maybe change them to correlated queries

Comment: You can use max() and min() function in subquery

Comment: Well simply said you can check each subquery on it's own and check what are the duplicates. If they are really the same just doubled, you can use `DISTINCT` on them. Otherwise, you'll need an aggregation (if possible). You can also join the tables instead and reform your statement to fix this issue.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Run your following subqueries individually to see which one is returning multipal rows based on that you may need to use DISTINCT (or Group By) or add another condition in where clause which makes it unique (depending on you data). If subqueries are returning more than one row then it can not be run as a full query.

```
 (SELECT AI.AUTH_CODE FROM AUTHORIZATION_INFO AI WHERE AI.PAYMENT_TYPE_CD = op.PAYMENT_TYPE_CD AND AI.ORDER_KEY = op.ORDER_KEY AND AI.AUTH_TYPE_CD = 'PRE' ) 

 (SELECT AI.AUTH_STATUS_DESC FROM AUTHORIZATION_INFO AI WHERE AI.PAYMENT_TYPE_CD = op.PAYMENT_TYPE_CD AND AI.ORDER_KEY = op.ORDER_KEY AND AI.AUTH_TYPE_CD = 'PRE' ) 

 (SELECT UPDATED_DT FROM SETTLEMENT_REFUND_RESP WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE_CODE = 'SET' AND PAYMENT_TYPE_CD ='DQP' AND ORDER_KEY = OP.ORDER_KEY ) REQUEST_DATE ,
```